# Setting Product Image From URL

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, hook-woocommerce

I am using Woocomerce. I want to set Product image and Product gallery image from external URL (i.e. google photos) other than media library.

Product Image

[image]

Product Gallery Image

[image]

Is there code or plugin to do that?

Answer (score 0):

you may use this plugin to solve.

[featured image from url plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/featured-image-from-url/)

by the way not recommend to use cause it may slow down the site speed. :(